# Key assignment scheme for sorting rows in table

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm looking for a scheme for assigning keys to rows in a table that would allow rows to be moved around and assigned new locations in the table without having to renumber the entire table.

Something like having keys 1, 2, 3, 4, then moving row "2" between 3 and 4 and then renaming it "3.5" (so you end up with 1, 3, 3.5, 4).  But the scheme needs to be "infinitely" extensible (permitting at least a few thousand "random" row moves before it would be normally be necessary to "normalize" the keys, and worst (most pathological) case allowing 25-50 such moves).

And the keys produced should be easily sorted, ideally I'd like them to be "naturally" ordered for a database (assume SQLite) query.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've settled, for the nonce, on a sort of poor-man's floating point scheme:  Use a 64-bit number, dedicate the left-hand 20 or so bits to being the integer increments, and then manage the right-hand bits as a fraction.  When inserting a value between two others, pick the value halfway between them (ie, their average value).

Comment: This should allow a minimum of 44 inserts in the most pathological case, and thousands in the "average" case.

Comment: Just curious, does whatever you're using not support floats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem reminds me of the [line numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_number) problem when a person was writing code in [BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC).  What most people did in this situation was take an educated guess on how many lines might be inserted in between two lines.  Then that guess would be the spacing between those lines.  So if you think you might have 2000 inserts between two elements, then you might make element1 have a key of 2000 and make element2 have a key of 4000.  Then we you want to put an element between element1 or element2 you either naively split the difference (3000) or if you have some intuition about how many elements would go on each side of element3, then you might weight it some (i.e. 3500 instead of 3000).

Another alternative (its really just the same thing but you are using a different numbering system) is to use floating point numbers which I believe you eluded to.  Between 1 and 2 would be 1.5.  Between 1.5 and 2 would be 1.75.  Between 1.5 and 1.75 would be 1.625, etc.

I would recommend against a key that is a string.  It is better to stick with numeric keys, and on top of that it is probably better to have integer type keys rather than floating point type keys if you can help it.

Comment: Yeah, what I've implemented so far is a 64-bit int with the first 20 bits being the "integer" part and the remainder the "fraction".  So adds to the bottom of the list increment the 19th bit from the left.  To insert between two lines, make the new key the average of the two enclosing key values.  The scheme could be extended to 2-3 64-bit values, if need be, but there's not an obvious way to simply make it self-extending.

Comment: Actually, it probably could be made self-extending by using a "blob" for the data.  Then sort ordering would be based on memcmp (at least in SQLite), so it would be equivalent to using an infinitely long integer.  There would be no auto extension to the left, of course, but if one allows, say, 6 bytes to the left of the "decimal point" then one would be able to enumerate the stars in the universe.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you could treat your table like a linked list.  Create a table with a unique ID, the key and it's next node and whatever other data you want.  Simply insert items sequentially, when you need to put a new item in between, simply swap the key values and the associated parent nodes.  The key values won't remain consistent, but that is what the additional unique ID is for and this works fine for ordering by the key as well.

Really, since you have order already specified by the key, you don't even need the 'next node'.  Your scheme as described above should be fine as long as you rename the keys of the other nodes in addition to the one you moved - i.e., 2 and 3 get their key values swapped.